# Dynamic Price with currency which differs from base currency

Tags: price, currency

In my store I need to calculate dynamic prices. I found the following code in several tutorials.

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after

$item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
$item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
$price = "your custom price logic";
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

For storeviews where BaseCurrency=StoreCurrency it works. But when the store Currency differs from the base currency i get unexpected results.

Example:

```
BaseCurrency = EUR
StoreCurrency = USD
```

Now I set the Price in my code to 1.

I would expect that magento displays either ~1.28$ or 1$

But it comes up with 0.78$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are doing the conversion wrong. Instead of `$price * $rate` you are doing $price / $rate (or the other way around).

I say this because `1.28 / 1 = 1/0.78` (aproximately)